# Trim line in string

Tags: c#, excel

I'm importing a .txt file into a Microsoft Excel sheet, it works great, but the problem is when i want to edit the content of the cells, for example I have my columns and then pass it to the Excel sheet, and this is what I get inside de cell "Patient Name:Robin", I only want to have in that cell the content that is after the ":". Here is my code.

```
  System.IO.StreamReader archivo = new System.IO.StreamReader(NombreFile);

 int lineacnt = 0;
    string[] ListInfo = new string[49];

for (int b = 1; b < 49; b++)
{
    ListInfo[b] = archivo.ReadLine();
    //Here I got an error of an object reference//
    **contenidoEMG[0, i] = ListInfo[7].Remove(ListInfo[7].IndexOf(':'));** 
    contenidoEMG[1, i] = ListInfo[11];
    contenidoEMG[2, i] = ListInfo[12];
```

Comment: You're introducing a new variable `contenidoEMG` where you get the error without showing it's declaration or initialization?

Comment: contenidoEMG is declared outside of this block of code.

Comment: Hold on a second there, you are doing a remove on string A but referncing an index in string B.  Is that what you ment to post?

Comment: I want to remove certain part of the line that is stored in ListInfo[7] but i get an error of object reference.

Comment: @carlos Then if your above code is exactly what you have, the problem is in the Remove() you are looking for an index in ListInfo[11] not in ListInfo[7]

Comment: Oops, but why I keep getting the error of an object reference in that same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string.Remove(int startIndex) returns a string with all characters following the startIndex removed.

```
var str = "patient name:Robin";
var newStr = str.Remove(str.IndexOf(':'));
Console.WriteLine(newStr); // prints 'patient name'
```

If you want Robin, the you should do `str.Remove(0, str.IndexOf(':')+1);`

Comment: ok, but can I use it in every element of ListInfo[], because I'm storing all the line in Listinfo[] and only want to store the content after the ":". Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you currently store 'patient name:Robin' in ListInfo[x] but you want to store just 'Robin'? Can you give an example?

Comment: no I´m reading a .txt file that contains 2315 lines,  I use Readline method to only read the first 49 lines, this lines were stored in my listinfo[], each line contains several data, one example is ¨Patient name : Robin¨ , ¨Patien Lastname : Smith¨ and so on, so I want to only get the content before the ¨:¨

Comment: What if there are less than 49 lines to read?  Are you checking that the array doesn't contain null or other bad data?

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing to check that `ListInfo[7]` is a proper string and not null?  That could be where you're having a problem.